# Problema con carga de imágenes en Picasso

Tags: java, android, picasso

**Buenas, estoy usando `Picasso` para la carga de imágenes que se obtienen de un `HTML` con la siguiente url como ejemplo: [Link](https://lectortmo.com/viewer/5f7372e84ee51421610959ba003445b4/cascade).  A la hora de extraer las url de las imágenes, las obtengo de manera perfecta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para corroborar que las urls funcionaran correctamente, las introduje en el navegador y pues cargan de manera correcta: [Link de la imagen](https://img1.japanreader.com/uploads/5f7372e84ee51421610959ba003445b4/8a2d1157.jpg)

Pero, a la hora de querer mostrarlas en mi aplicación pues no sucede absolutamente nada, se queda en blanco la pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de la actividad:

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private TMOnlineLectorAdaptador adapter;
private ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> tmoLectorClases = new ArrayList<>();
private String url = "";
private TimerTask _timerTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tmonline_lector);

    url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvCapitulosSeleccion);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new TMOnlineLectorAdaptador(tmoLectorClases, TMOnlineLector.this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Content content = new Content();
    content.execute();
}

private class Content extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, ArrayList<TMOLectorClase>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> items) {
        super.onPostExecute(items);
        //Actualizar información
        adapter.updateData(items);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        tmoLectorClases.clear();
        try {
            String nuevaUrl = Jsoup.connect(url).followRedirects(true).execute().url().toExternalForm();
            Log.d("Items", "Url: " + nuevaUrl);

            if(nuevaUrl.contains("/paginated")){
                nuevaUrl = nuevaUrl.replaceAll("/paginated", "/cascade");
                Log.d("URLS", "doInBackground: " + nuevaUrl);

                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(nuevaUrl).get();
                Log.d("Items", "Url: " + doc);

                Elements data = doc.select("div.img-container.text-center");
                for (Element e : data){
                    String imgUrl = "";
                    if(e.select("div.img-container.text-center").size() > 0)
                    imgUrl = e.select("img").get(0).attr("data-src");
                    Log.d("finalurl", "url nueva:" + nuevaUrl + "\nimagenes: " + imgUrl);
                    //String imgUrl = e.select("img").attr("data-src");
                    tmoLectorClases.add(new TMOLectorClase(imgUrl));
                }
            }else{
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(nuevaUrl).get();

                Elements data = doc.select("div.img-container.text-center");
                for (Element e : data){
                    String imgUrl = e.select("img").attr("data-src");
                    Log.d("finalurl", "url nueva:" + nuevaUrl + "\nimagenes: " + imgUrl);
                    tmoLectorClases.add(new TMOLectorClase(imgUrl));
                }
            }
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tmoLectorClases;
    }
}
```

Este es el código del adaptador:

```
public class TMOnlineLectorAdaptador extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TMOnlineLectorAdaptador.ViewHolder>{
    private ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> tmoLectorClases;
    private Context context;
    PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;

    public TMOnlineLectorAdaptador(ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> tmoItems, Context context) {
        this.tmoLectorClases = tmoItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TMOnlineLectorAdaptador.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adaptador_lectortmo, parent, false);
        return new TMOnlineLectorAdaptador.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final TMOnlineLectorAdaptador.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TMOLectorClase tmoLectorClase = this.tmoLectorClases.get(position);
        Picasso.get().load(tmoLectorClase.getImg()).into(holder.iv);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tmoLectorClases.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageView iv;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
            super(view);
            iv = view.findViewById(R.id.ivPaginas);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    }

    public void setFilter(ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> newList) {
        tmoLectorClases = new ArrayList<>();
        tmoLectorClases.addAll(newList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void updateData(ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> items) {
        this.tmoLectorClases = items;
    }
}
```

¿Alguno puede ver el error que estoy cometiendo? Es que ya no se donde buscarlo

**Actualización:**

`Debugeando` cada línea de mi código, pensé que el problema era de mi aplicación a la hora de pasar el `link` por el `array` implementado en la línea de `Picasso`. Pero, no, de hecho incluso ahí llegan bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que me puse a leer por todo el foro tanto en **SO Ingles como Español** pero no he dado con ninguna solución puesto que hay momentos en los que las imágenes cargan bien y otros en los que no. Ejemplo: **hoy a las 13 hs las imágenes cargaron bien, a las 14 hs no se mostraban.** Ingresando al `link` de cada imagen a las 14hs por el **navegador** funcionaban los `links` y cargaban las imágenes pero en la aplicación no. Por lo que, añadí esta línea al `Manifest`:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Pero, el problema persiste. Intenté usando la librería `Glide` pero esa ni siquiera carga otras imágenes mediante `URL`. ¿ALguien tiene o conoce de alguna otra solución posible?

**Actualización 2:**

Layout del Adaptador:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/CardView.Light"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/blanco">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/blanco">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/ivPaginas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Layout de la actividad:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.TMO.TMOnlineLector"
    android:background="@color/blanco"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvLector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Agrega tu layout porque este podría ser el problema que no permite desplegar las imágenes.

Comment: Hola, he añadido el layout del adaptador y la de la actividad @Jorgesys

Comment: @FranqBalsamo, he revisado lo que agregaste, te quería preguntar si revisaste el AsyncTask, revisa el LogCat cuando no agrega los datos, tienes tu proyecto en un github?

Comment: ya lo tengo, permiteme revisar!

Comment: Vale, ¡gracias!

Comment: Hola Franqo, revisa la actualización de mi respuesta, y coméntame resultados @FranqoBalsamo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a la imagen que muestras,el ArrayList `tmoLectorClaseArrayList` contiene las imágenes y obtienes la url de acuerdo a la variable `position` lo cual es correcto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el Adapter todo es correcto, creas la clase Holder donde obtienes la referencia del ImageView:

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
ImageView iv;

```
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
        super(view);
        iv = view.findViewById(R.id.ivPaginas);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    }
}
```

y en el método `onBindViewHolder` cargas correctamente la imagen dentro del `ImageView`

```
Picasso.get().load(tmoLectorClase.getImg()).into(holder.iv);
```

Lo que deduce que pueden ser dos cosas:

Primeramente es importante que asegures tener definido dentro del AndroidManifest.xml el permiso para internet:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

El problema es el layout, ya que el ImageView puede tener propiedades que provocan que nose despliegue correcamente en la pantalla, por ejemplo si usas un ConstraintLatout.

Agrega tu layout porque este podría ser el problema que no permite desplegar las imágenes.

---

Con respecto a :

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

no es necesario puesto que las url de imagen son `https://`.

---

- Actualización:

Al revisar el funcionamiento de tu app a detalle, lo primero que me llamo la atención es que cargaba una pantalla en blanco, regrese y trate de nuevo y ya pude ver las imágenes.

En realidad tu app no falla a menos que no tenga conexión a internet, pero da la impresión de que no va a cargar absolutamente nada, para evitar precisamente esta situación Google recomienda usar una barra de progreso ([ProgressBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar)) de forma indeterminada en la interfaz de usuario para que el usuario sepa que esta esperando alguna respuesta.

Para esto te sugiero modificar la vista que cargaría el `RecyclerView` agregando un `ProgressBar`, `tmonline_lector_adaptador.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/CardView.Light"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/blanco">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/ivPaginas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

y dentro de tu Adapter `TMOnlineLectorAdaptador.java` modifica para agregar a `Picasso` un Callback en el cual quitaría el `ProgressBar` cuando la Imagen se cargué, incluso puedes detectar

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final TMOnlineLectorAdaptador.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final TMOLectorClase tmoLectorClase = this.tmoLectorClaseArrayList.get(position);
    //Carga con Picasso
    Picasso.get().load(tmoLectorClase.getImg()).into(holder.ivPaginas, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(actividad,"Ocurrió un error cargando la imagen : " + tmoLectorClase.getImg(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
}
```

obviamente agrega en tu clase `ViewHolder` la obtención de la referencia del `ProgresBar`:

```
   public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageView ivPaginas;
        ProgressBar progressBar;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
            super(view);
            ivPaginas = view.findViewById(R.id.ivPaginas);
            progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    }
```

De esta forma obtendrías el siguiente efecto, se mostraría un indicador el cual indica que esta realizándose la carga de la imagen, de esta forma el usuario no tendría la impresión de que no se esta cargando nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo mismo para el layout de la Activity, agrega un ProgressBar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.TMO.TMOnlineLector"
    android:background="@color/blanco"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvLector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

y cuando el Asynctask responda lo quitas:

```
  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> items) {
        super.onPostExecute(items);
        //Actualizar información
        tmOnlineLectorAdaptador.updateData(items);
        tmOnlineLectorAdaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
        findViewById(R.id.progressbar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: Buenas, el permiso está definido en el manifest. He agregado el layout como mencionas

Comment: Gracias por la actualización, con respecto a lo de que carga en blanco, si pues no había puesto los prograssbar. Gracias por la respuesta, en caso de que este no sea el problema, haré otra pregunta

Comment: Claro que si Franqo, saludos.